# shell adding string to an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am having some trouble adding a string to an array within a loop. For some reason it always adds the same line. Here is my code:

```
declare -a properties
counter=0

while read line
do

    if [[ ${line} == *=* ]]
    then
        properties[${counter}]=${line}
        (( counter=counter + 1 ))
    fi
done < ${FILE}

for x in ${!properties[@]}
do
    echo "the value is $properties[x]"
done
```

For some reason each element in the array is the first line in the file. I must be doing something wrong, just not sure what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Change `$properties[x]` in your `echo` line to `${properties[$x]}`...

Comment: This is a Bash script. Why do you tag ksh?

Comment: The script will work in both `bash` and `ksh93` if the `declare ...` is removed.  Simple arrays are created on the fly in both.

Answer (score 4):

Try this script:

```
declare -a properties
while read line
do
   [[ "${line}" == *=* ]] && properties+=("$line")
done < "${FILE}"

for x in "${properties[@]}"
do
   echo "the value is "$x"
done
```

Comment: Great improvement, but please double-quote `${properties[@]}` to prevent unwanted shell expansions.

Comment: This eliminates the bug in the original script by looping x over the expanded values, instead of the index.  The changes in the upper loop detract from the original bug.

Answer (score 1):

As @twalberg [mentions in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121562/shell-adding-string-to-an-array#comment31784938_21121562), the problem is not in the top loop, but in the bottom one:

```
for x in ${!properties[@]}
do
    echo "the value is $properties[x]"
done
```

Array references *always* need braces `{ ... }` to expand properly.

> For some reason each element in the array is the first line in the
>   file.

Not so. The array is correctly populated, but you need to change the reference to the array from:

```
echo "the value is $properties[x]"
```

to:

```
echo "the value is ${properties[x]}"
```

Just a simple oversight.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem and showing me that variable references in array subscripts need not be `$`-prefixed (`[x]` vs. `[$x]`) (and that subscripts can even be arithmetic expressions).

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to add an element to an array is to simply use the syntax:

```
VARNAME+=("content")
```

Also, as written, your bug may be here:

```
(( counter=counter + 1 ))
```

It probably should be one of these three:

```
(( counter=$counter + 1 ))
counter+=1
counter=$[$counter+1]
counter=$(($counter + 1))
```

Comment: Your recommendation for building the array is helpful, but please consider removing the rest of your answer: Not only is `(( counter=counter + 1 ))` correct (albeit clumsy), your alternatives are not an improvement and in the case of `counter+=1` incorrect. If anything, `(( ++counter ))` is the most concise form to use.

Comment: Correct, but does not answer the question.  And then, you missed an option: `[[ ${line} == *=* ]] && properties[counter++]=${line}` :-)

Answer (score 0):

This KornShell (ksh) script worked fine for me. Let me know if anything.

**readFileArrayExample.ksh**

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

file=input.txt
typeset -i counter=0

while read line
do
    if [[ ${line} == *=* ]]; then
        properties[${counter}]="${line}"
        ((counter = counter + 1))
        echo "counter:${counter}"
    fi
done < "${file}"

#echo ${properties[*]}

for x in "${properties[@]}"
do
    echo "${x}"
done
```

**readFileArrayExample.ksh Output:**

```
@:/tmp #ksh readFileArrayExample.ksh
counter:1
counter:2
counter:3
a=b
a=1
b=1
@:/tmp #
```

**input.txt**

```
a-b
a+b
a=b
a=1
b=1
1-a
```